# AngularJS: No cargan las rutas creadas

Tags: angularjs, ui.router, rutas

Tengo el siguiente problema, no cargan las rutas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi directorio contiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El HTML es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las rutas tienen la siguiente configuracion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé cambiando las rutas por:

```
template: '/views/partials/usuarios.html'
template: '/partials/usuarios.html'
```

Pero no llega a cargar, ¿Qué me falta?

Answer (score 0):

Oh rayos!
Al fin encontré el problemas, era tan simple:

Yo usé:

```
template: '/views/partials/usuarios.html'
```

Debió ser:

```
templateUrl: '/views/partials/usuarios.html'
```

Eso es todo.